# Firebase Phone Authentication for mac catalyst

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, mac-catalyst

**Context**

I am in the process to implement Mac Catalyst in my iOS project. Everything is alright so far except the Google Firebase support.

I am authenticating the user with their phone number. Firebase does this in a two step process. First the device receives a silent push notification & then they are asked to enter their OTP.

The first time I tried, a window opened in safari. It just checked if I am a robot or not. Every other time I tried the window didn't come back.

All this is working with iOS. It just doesn't work on my mac.

**Problem**

I am getting the following warning:

[Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003014] Running InstanceID on a simulator doesn't have APNS. Use prod profile by default.

**Code**

```
Internet.signIn(with: code) { (error) in

// This line aka the closure is never executed

            if error != nil{

                alert("Something went wrong", "Try resending the SMS")

                return
            }

            alert("Verified", "Let's continue with entering further user information now") {

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "userWasVerifiedSegue", sender: self)

            }
        }
```

**Approaches**

- I edited my scheme & changed it to "release".
- Tried to add a new mac certificate on developer.apple but it doesn't allow me to enter the bundle id.

Comment: Did you make sure to activate push notifications in XCode?  I use a similar process in my own app, and I'm currently having a similar but not identical issue with push notifications.

Comment: Hey any luck with this? We are having exactly the same issue

Comment: Anyone figure this one out? Same issue here